# Online collaborative list without registration

Tags: web-apps, collaboration, information-management

I'm in a food co-op that has a grocery store. When some product is missing and we need to order more, we write the name of the product on a whiteboard in the store. Then the people operating the shift need to email the supply squad the list. Sometimes the list gets wiped before anyone does anything with it, sometimes it just gets missed … you get the point.

I'm looking for an alternative way to list missing products.

The features needed:

1. A persistent list with a URL that links to it
2. Adding items
3. Removing items
4. Optional - see when an item was added

I'd prefer no voting and other features; we don't vote and it just adds noise.

There are also some constraints:

1. It needs to be a site (preferably hosted, but we can self-host if necessary) and not an app - not everybody in the co-op has a smartphone
2. No registration/login required - it's way too much overhead and people will not do it
3. Hebrew support is a must

From what I've found online, Chacy was the closest one, but it doesn't support Hebrew and I couldn't find how to remove an item.

Comment: I'm debating your requirement 2 *No registration/login required - it's way too much overhead and people will not do it*. You rely on security by obscurity, and it's hardly necessary, because sites like these usually remember your login with cookies (you can test that).

Comment: discuss with a software company your needs and they will design a website specifically for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [flask](http://flask.io/) to be satisfying. Only one person needs to register in order to save the list, and then everybody else can just go to the URL created for that list.

It's also extremely easy to use and doesn't have unnecessary and disruptive features (for the task at hand) like voting.